# Update records Zoho api v2 symbols

Tags: php, api, zoho

When I use the updateRecords method, to put new data into the fields in the zoho, some fields not updated. These fields have symbols in the title like '?' '/' '(' 
How to solve this problem? 
Fields: "Date/Time" and "email_confirmed_?" empty, but "Last_Name" and  "User_group" was updated and has data.

```
$header = array("Authorization:Zoho-oauthtoken $token", 'Content-Type: application/json');
$fields =  ["data"=> ["Last_Name" => "User Name",
                      "Date/Time"=>"2018-09-25T13:23:39+02:00",
                      "email_confirmed_?"=>"yes",
                      "User_group"=>"new user"]];

        $fields = json_encode($fields);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        $result =curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hey Eugene! You’l lneed to give us a little more information. For example, post the code you’ve written. Give examples of what you’re getting and what you’d like it to say. Also would be useful to know how you’re using the API, maybe through a Composer package?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have assumed your custom fields API names. You could try "[Field Meta Data](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#Field-Meta-Data)" API to get the API name of your custom fields.

```
    {
        "custom_field": false,
        "lookup": {},
        "convert_mapping": {
            "Potentials": null,
            "Contacts": null,
            "Accounts": null
        },
        "visible": true,
        "field_label": "Lead Owner",
        "length": 120,
        "view_type": {
            "view": true,
            "edit": true,
            "quick_create": false,
            "create": true
        },
        "read_only": false,
        "api_name": "Owner",
        "unique": {},
        "data_type": "ownerlookup",
        "formula": {},
        "currency": {},
        "id": "410888000000000553",
        "decimal_place": null,
        "pick_list_values": [],
        "auto_number": {}
    }
```

The above is a sample response of the API. You can notice the difference between the "field_label" and "api_name".